# Protractor get value from ng-reflect-model

Tags: angular, protractor

I am trying to get value from ng-reflect-model :
Code: var foo = element(by.css('ng-reflect-model'));

```
getting error like: No element found using locator: By(css selector, ng-reflect-model).

thanks in advance.
```

Comment: var foo = element(by.css('.ng-reflect-model')) can you try with dot

Comment: I tried with using element(by.css('.ng-reflect-model')) . error is;No element found using locator: By(css selector, .ng-reflect-model).

Comment: ng-reflect-model is a Attribute you cannot access as class 
try to get value with model name 
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model